# jquery siblings() seems to include selector if there are siblings but not if not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django-templates

I have an ajax call with the following success function:

```
            success: function(response){
                console.log($(response).siblings());
                $(response).siblings().each(function(){
                    alert("foo");
                    var thing_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[0];
                    alert(thing_id);
                    $("#"+thing_id).append(this);
                })
```

where response is rendered html using this django template (slightly anonymized):

```
{% for thing in things %}
    <div id="{{ thing.something.id }}-pc">
        <div>
            <span class="tablename">Something Else</span>
            {% include '<some template>' with table=thing.something_else %}
        </div>

    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

the docs for sibling() state that the selector is not included, which is what I see if I only have one `thing in things` in my template, but if I have more than one, I get both top level divs alerted in the loop.

What's going on?!

EDIT (better question): why am I getting both top level divs when there are 2, but 0 when there is only 1, when I call `siblings()` on `$(response)`?

Seems like I'm misunderstanding what I'm selecting with `$(response)`. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: What are you expecting? `siblings` will grab all siblings but you can filter with a class `siblings('.class')`

Comment: very hard to follow what you want to have happen

Comment: hopefully my edit clarified. I am expecting that if there are two top level divs, I will get one thing when I ask for `.siblings()` (because presumably `$(response)` is pointing to the first one and I will get it's only sibling). However, in reality, I'm getting two things.

Comment: @nnnnnn this is closer to what I need to know. So what am I selecting when I say `$(response)`?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment to make it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"So what am I selecting when I say* `$(response)`?"

That gives you a jQuery object that includes *all* of the top-level elements in your `response` string. If there were, say, three top-level elements then `$(response).length` will be `3`.

`$(response).siblings()` then gives you all of the siblings of all of the top-level elements, and because each is a sibling of the other(s) this again returns all of the top-level elements.

If there is only one top-level element then it has no siblings.

So obviously `.siblings()` is the wrong method to be using here, but I'm not sure what to advise you to use instead because your desired result is still unclear.

You can loop through each top-level element with:

```
$(response).each(function() {...
```

To get a particular one you can use `.eq(someZeroBasedIndex)`, e.g., `$(response).eq(1)` to get the second.

To get all except the first you can use `$(response).slice(1)`.

Comment: So weirdly, when I have 2 top level things, `$(response).each()` gives me 3 things-- the two divs I expect with a "text" node in between. What's up with that?

Comment: Is there text in between the elements in your source string? You can get just the top-level divs with `$(response).filter("div").each(...)`.

Comment: That's the weird thing, as you can see from my template, there is no text between the elements. I'll try the filter, thanks.

Comment: You do have whitespace inbetween. But anyway `.filter()` should do the trick.

Comment: Ah, thought all whitespace would be collapsed and shouldn't count. Good to know. Thanks!